# Facebook schedule for pages goes into albums instead of directly on the wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I run a page on Facebook and have an issue where if I schedule photos, it puts them into an an album called "photos" rather than just updating them as a wall post/wall photos.

It's tediously annoying and brings down interaction of my funny pictures page.

Is there a way to stop them from being put into the photos album?

Comment: Are you using an app to schedule photos?  It sounds like an issue with that app.

Comment: I'm using the Facebook wall post scheduler. Which is new and it doesn't put photos as wall posts.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and believe that Facebook is treating scheduled photos as API photos. I found a clue here: [hootsuite](http://help.hootsuite.com/entries/20448527-images-not-posting-to-facebook-wall-but-adds-to-photos), which says:

> Hello,
>
> Facebook's API regarding photos posted from 3rd party clients is time specific. For instance, if you post one picture during a day, it will show up on your wall. If you post three within an hour, all three photos will be grouped together under one wall post.
>
> Thank you :)
> Chris, Support Captain
> Enterprise Support
> January 24, 2012 11:10

I'm going to try scheduling 2 photos and 1 link to see what happens.

Comment: And? What happened?